# How to configure git in WebStorm

Tags: git, webstorm, jetbrains-ide

I just installed **WebStorm** from JetBrains, and cloned my repo using **SourceTree** to disk. Then I opened the project in WebStorm and everything is working except the git in WebStorm.

In SourceTree everything is working fine, but in WebStorm I can't do anything, I can't pull, commit or whatever.

I'm receiving this popup: `Can't start Git: git.exe`. I know that probably I must set the good path to this file, but I don't know where it is.

[image]

Please could you give me an advice where should I find this file, or how to resolve this problem?

Remember that in SourceTree this repository is working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to click on the "Fix it" option, and change the path to the git.exe file.  As Windows is strange (personal opinion, not answer fact) this can be in a number of locations.  From [this github page](https://github.com/bouvet-openlab/p2pcommunication/wiki/Set-git-executable-path) it could be in one of the following locations:

> **Git** - C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin
>   **SmartGit** -    C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\SmartGit\git\bin\git.exe
>   **GitHub For Windows** -
>   C:\Users\'username'\AppData\Local\GitHub\PortableGit_'numbersandletters'\cmd\git.exe

Answer (score 3):

You may have to install git from the link below, then use the 'Fix it' link if it's not found automatically.

https://git-scm.com/download/win